# Reordering bootstrap 4 columns

Tags: html, grid, bootstrap-grid

I'm making a component with Nuxt.js and Vue.js. This component has a bootstrap grid with 2 columns, both col-6. Now i want to add a function where i can reorder the columns, so i can switch the positions to the left or right. i've been trying to reorder them with the push and pull method included in bootstrap. But i cant seem to get it working.

This is my code. I would really appreciate some help.

Code:

```
<template>
<section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h4>
                            {{ blok.title }}
                        </h4>

                        <p>
                            {{ blok.text }}
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="button">
                        <LinkType :link="blok.link" :linkText="blok.linkText">
                            {{ blok.linkText ? blok.linkText : 'Lees meer' }}
                        </LinkType>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                <div class="image" :style="{ paddingTop: getRatio }">
                    <img :src="blok.image"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to just add class when you want to change div order. I have added order class on first column div `<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 order-2">`

See below code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 order-2">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h4>
                                {{ blok.title }}
                            </h4>
    
                            <p>
                                {{ blok.text }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="button">
                            <LinkType :link="blok.link" :linkText="blok.linkText">
                                {{ blok.linkText ? blok.linkText : 'Lees meer' }}
                            </LinkType>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                    <div class="image" :style="{ paddingTop: getRatio }">
                        <img :src="blok.image"/>
                        second box here
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>


  </script>
</body>

</html>
```